# bash, script to git add one file and commit

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to create a script to do this:

```
git add "file"
git commit -m "Comment"
```

My idea is to run:

```
gac "file" "Comment"
```

I know I can do something similar but for all files, with:

```
echo 'alias gac="/path/to/gitaddcommit.sh"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

And the `.sh` would be:

```
!/bin/bash
git add .
echo “Enter commit message: “
git commit -am “$commitMessage”
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you need two things :

1. A bin folder where you can put every sh script you want to use everywhere.
2. More knowledge about shell scripting and how you can get argv (in your ex: 'file' 'Comment')

So first go to your `/home/<username>` then `mkdir bin && cd bin && pwd`
then copy the pwd and add it into your `PATH` env variable inside your .bashrc

path example: PATH='/bin/:/sbin/:/home//bin

Then `source ~/.bashrc` you can now use every sh script inside you bin folder everywhere.

Cool so first problem done !
you don't have to do `echo alias gac="/path/to/gitaddcommit.sh"' >> ~/.bash_profile` anymore.

Now second problem here a post that can help you [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31414/how-can-i-pass-a-command-line-argument-into-a-shell-script)
And let me show you for your example :

```
cd ~/bin && vi gac.sh
```

Now the script :

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "Usage: ./gac FILENAME COMMIT_MESSAGE" >&2
  exit 1
fi
git add "$1"
git commit -am "$2"
```

First we check the number or arg then git add and commit.
Simple and fast maybe checking if arg one is a file might be a good idea too.
PS: i'm going to re write my post ahah

Comment: Thanks, I already have the alias to my sh file (I have like 40 scripts that use daily, but none of them were mine),  I'm trying  create now the scripts that I said. Thanks, I will check your answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have in my .bashrc:

```
ga () 
{ 
    if test "$1" != "-f" && git rev-parse HEAD > /dev/null 2>&1 && ! git diff-index --quiet HEAD; then
        echo 'Repo is dirty.  -f to force' 1>&2;
        return 1;
    fi;
    git add "$@";
    list=$(git diff --name-only --cached | tr \\n \ );
    git commit -m "Add $list"
}
```

The commit message is autogenerated, but you could easily modify it to prompt the user or take it from somewhere else.